# Probability question involving Exponential and Poisson distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The number of insects hitting a windscreen of a car travelling from Johannesburg to Nelspruit follows a Poisson distribution.

The variance of the waiting time between insect strikes is 36 seconds$^2$.

If an insect has just hit the windscreen, calculate the probability that the next insect will hit the windscreen between 10 and 14 seconds. **(I'm assuming they meant between 10 and 14 seconds from now)**

**This is what I've done so far :) thanks for the help**

Let $X$ = number of insects hitting a windscreen

$X \sim P(\lambda)$

Let $Y$ = waiting time between insect strikes

$Y \sim Exp(\lambda)$

Since the variance of the **waiting time between insect strikes** is 36 seconds$^2$, we use the variance according to the exponential distribution.

$$Var(Y) = \frac{1}{{\lambda}^2}$$
$$36 = \frac{1}{{\lambda}^2}$$
$$\lambda^2 = \frac{1}{36}$$
$$\lambda = \frac{1}{6}$$

**$$P(10<Y<14) = P(Y>10) - P(Y \geq 14)?$$**

I know how to work out $P(Y>10)$ with an exponential distribution but not $P(Y \geq 14)$

Comment: Are you sure that $P(a<Y<b)=P(Y>a)-P(Y\geq b)$ ?

Comment: Well. It's exponential so the probability that it is greater than a - the probability that it is greater then b (taking into account that if it is equal to b then it must also be subtracted because Y must be less then and not equal to b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the exponential distribution is continuous, and therefore $$P(Y=y)=0$$ for every $y \in \mathbb R$. In particular, this implies that $$P(Y\ge y)=P(Y>y)$$ and in your case $$P(Y\ge 14)=P(Y>14)$$ which you can calculate as you know.

Comment: You are welcome, good luck with it!!